# how to pass array data and user entered data into database through controller using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="../../assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/angular-ui-bootstrap-0.9.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angularjs/script.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/paginationjs/dirPagination.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-cloak data-ng-app="UserModule" data-ng-controller="UserController" ng-init="GetOutlet();GetCategory();GetTables()">

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-panel">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-right: 0px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 no-pad-left">
                            <h3>New Order</h3>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="card noborder-card">
                            <div class="content">
                                  <!-- ************* Add User Modal start *************-->
                        <form role="form" id="AddUserForm" name="AddUserForm" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate=""  data-ng-submit="AddOrderData(AddUser)">

                            <div class="card popup-card">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        <h3 class="text-center">{{OutletName}}</h3>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            <div ng-show="NewOrderDiv">    
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                           <label class="control-label" for="restaurant" style="display: -webkit-inline-box;"> 
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control border-input" id="parcel" name="parcel"   data-ng-model="parcel"  /> &nbsp;&nbsp;Parcel </label>
                                            <div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted || AddUserForm.parcel.$dirty && AddUserForm.parcel.$invalid">
                                                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.parcel.$error.required">Parcel is required.</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    <div ng-if="parcel">    
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                           <label class="control-label" for="Name"> Name <span class="error">*</span></label>
                                         <input class="form-control border-input" type="text" id="personname" name="username" required data-ng-model="$parent.personname" data-ng-minlength="3" pattern="^[a-zA-Z- .]+" >

                                        <div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted || AddUserForm.personname.$dirty && AddUserForm.username.$invalid">
                                            <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.personname.$error.required">Name is required.</small>
                                            <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.personname.$error.minlength">Name is required to be at least 3 characters</small>
                                            <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.personname.$error.pattern">Name should be alphabetic.</small>
                                            <small class="error" data-ng-show="UserNameExists">Name already Exists.</small>
                                        </div>
                                        </div> 

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="contactno">Contact # <span class="error">*</span></label>
                                            <input class="form-control border-input" type="text" id="contactno" name="contactno" maxlength="10"  data-ng-model="$parent.contactno" data-ng-minlength="10" data-ng-maxlength="10" pattern="[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" required="" data-ng-change="CheckContact()"/>
                                            <div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted || AddUserForm.contactno.$dirty && AddUserForm.contactno.$invalid">
                                                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.contactno.$error.required">Contact # is required.</small>
                                                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.contactno.$error.minlength">Contact # is required to be at least 10 characters</small>
                                                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.contactno.$error.maxlength">Contact # cannot be longer than 10 characters</small>
                                                <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.contactno.$error.pattern">Contact #   must be number only & start from 6-9</small>
                                                <small class="error" data-ng-show="ContactExists">Contact # already exists</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    

                                    <div ng-if="!parcel">    
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                           <label class="control-label" for="Table No">Table No <span class="error">*</span></label>
                                            <select class="form-control border-input" type="text" id="tableno" name="tableno" ng-model="$parent.tableno" required >
                                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                                <option ng-repeat="table in TablesArray" value="{{table.TableId}}">{{table.TableName}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                                <div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted || AddUserForm.tableno.$dirty && AddUserForm.tableno.$invalid">
                                                    <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.tableno.$error.required">Table No is required.</small>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                           <label class="control-label" for="PAX">PAX <span class="error">*</span></label>
                                            <input class="form-control border-input" type="text" id="pax" name="pax" ng-model="$parent.pax" data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" required >
                                                <div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted || AddUserForm.pax.$dirty && AddUserForm.pax.$invalid">
                                                    <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.pax.$error.required">PAX is required.</small>
                                                    <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.pax.$error.pattern">PAX should be numeric ex:1234567890</small>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="row"  ng-repeat="cat in CategoryItems">
                                        <div class="col-md-12"> 
                                            <div class="panel-group">
                                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <span ng-click="GetItems(cat.CategoryId,$index)"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{cat.PkId}}"><input type="hidden" value="{{cat.CategoryId}}">{{cat.CategoryName}}</a></span>
                                                  </h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapse{{cat.PkId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="tank-card tank-sectoin">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <strong>ItemName</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <strong>Quantity</strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <span ng-repeat="item in ItemsArray[$index]">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <input type="hidden"  value="{{item.ItemId}}">
                                                                <input type="hidden"  value="{{item.CatId}}">
                                                                {{item.ItemId}}
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                     <input class="form-control border-input" type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity{{$index}}" ng-model="cat.quantity" 
                                                                     data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" >

                                                                    <div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted || AddUserForm.quantity{{$index}}.$dirty && AddUserForm.quantity{{$index}}.$invalid">
                                                                        <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.quantity{{$index}}.$error.required">Quantity is required.</small>
                                                                        <small class="error" data-ng-show="AddUserForm.quantity{{$index}}.$error.pattern">Quantity should be numeric ex:1234567890</small>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <!--<div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>-->
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" data-ng-hide="submitbtn" class="btn btn-success">ORDER SUMMERY</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-ng-click="GoBack()">BACK</button>
                                    </div>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div> <!--row  end-->
                            </div>

                            </div>  <!-- card end-->


                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" data-ng-show="showWarningAlert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="switchBool('showWarningAlert')">×</button><strong>&nbsp;{{WarningAlert}}</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-ng-show="showSuccessAlert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="switchBool('showSuccessAlert')">×</button>
                                <strong>&nbsp;{{SuccessAlert}}</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        </form>  <!--form end-->
            <!-- ****************Add User Modal start **********-->
                            </div><!-- content-->
                        </div><!--card-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

////js start here

```
 var ListUsers = angular.module("UserModule", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','ui.bootstrap'])
ListUsers.controller("UserController", function ($scope, $timeout, $http, jsonFilter)
{   
    $scope.NewOrderDiv = true;
    $scope.FinalOrderDiv = true;
    $scope.showWarningAlert = false;    
    $scope.showSuccessAlert = false;

    var logResult = function (data, status, headers, config)
    {
        return data;
    };

    $scope.GetCategory= function()
    {
        $http.get("get_category_data.php").success(function(data)
        {  
            $scope.query = {}
            $scope.queryBy = '$';
            $scope.CategoryItems = data;
            if(data=="null")
            {
                $scope.ViewRecords = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.ViewRecords = true;
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.GetOutlet= function()
    {
        $http.get("load_outlets.php").success(function(data)
        {  
            $scope.OutletName = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.ItemsArray = [];
    $scope.GetItems= function(CategoryId,index)
    {
        $http.post("get_category_wise_items.php", { 'CategoryId': CategoryId })
        .success(function(data)
        {  
            $scope.ItemsArray[index] = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.TablesArray = [];
    $scope.GetTables= function()
    {
        $http.get("get_category_wise_tables.php")
        .success(function(data)
        {  
            $scope.TablesArray = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.AddOrderData = function ()
    {
        $scope.submitted = true;

        var CatId=new Array();
        var ItemId=new Array();
        var quantity=new Array();

        for( var i = 0; i < $scope.CategoryItems.length; i++ ) 
        {
            CatId.push($scope.CategoryItems[i].CatId);
            ItemId.push($scope.CategoryItems[i].ItemId);
            quantity.push($scope.CategoryItems[i].quantity);
        }

        alert($scope.CatId);
        alert($scope.ItemId);
        alert($scope.quantity);

        alert(CatId);
        alert(ItemId);
        alert(quantity);

        $http.post('order_process.php',{'parcel':$scope.parcel,'personname':$scope.personname,'contactno':$scope.contactno,'tableno':$scope.tableno,'pax':$scope.pax})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {
            if(data=="Success")
            {
                $scope.SuccessAlert = "User added successfully";
                $scope.showSuccessAlert = true;
                $scope.showWarningAlert = false;

                $scope.AddUser = {};
                $scope.AddUserForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.AddUserForm.$setUntouched();

                $timeout(function () { $scope.showSuccessAlert = false;
                                        $scope.ShowAddOutlet = false;
                                        window.location.href="list-users.php"}, 1000);

            }
            else
            {
                $scope.WarningAlert = data;
                $scope.showWarningAlert = true;
                $timeout(function () { $scope.showWarningAlert = false; $scope.submitted = false;}, 5000);
            }
        })

        .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
        {
            $scope.WarningAlert = logResult(data, status, headers, config);
        });
    };

    $scope.switchBool = function (value) {
        $scope[value] = !$scope[value];
    };
});
```

Please Find the Attachment.

Here Categories and Items are fetching from database dynamically.

calling like ng-repeat="cat in CategoryItems"

Items fetching from Database Using GetItems(cat.CategoryId,$index) function

ng-repeat="item in ItemsArray[$index]"

Here Problem is if User entering Quantity(input) for one item it is applying for remaining items(inputs).

and also Unable to pass the user entered input fields i.e.,(ItemId, Quantity) for respected categories into the controller.

I want to save above data into the database.

Kindly help us.

Thanks you in Advance

[image: atachment]